# Registry not being modified with C# application

Tags: c#, registry

I have the following snipped of code that is running within a Windows Service.

The service watches the LAN and changes the proxy settings accordingly, the problem is that for some reason the proxy settings are not being updated.

The application is running under the Local System Account but the registry stil ldoes nto change:

Anyone have any ideas?

```
using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", true))
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        key.SetValue("ProxyEnable", Convert.ToInt32(enable), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        //I/O Flushes
        key.Flush();
        key.Close();
        return;
    }

    //Exception thrown here to test if key is valid.
}
```

Comment: Does the service user have privileges to change the registry?

Comment: The OS is 32bit Windows XP SP3, sorry about the confusion with the service account, its the Local System Account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running in the local system account, there is no HKEY_Current_User.

In fact, in many cases, even if you are running a service as a user account, there will be no HKEY_CURRENT_USER, because the service generally won't create a full windows station -- it just uses the user account for authentication, and not the profile.

This is 1 of several reasons that many COM automation-capable applications are not able to be used by services.

You will be able to access HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, though.

**Edit**
If you run your service as a specific user account (or if you have the thread in your service impersonate a specific user account), you might be able to use RegOpenCurrentUser function to retrieve a handle to the key you want, and then use RegistryKey.FromHandle to use it from the .Net API's.

Comment: In that case, shouldnt there be an exception?

Comment: the problem is the authentication, the application will be running as a service for several users that depending on what network there on the proxy changes, does this mean that i have to grant them users the right to change the registry? and then run under there account ?

Comment: I have just done a test and it looks like your correct, i created a console app and done so open/get.set/close test and there all fine, what account should i run it on in order to change the settings for the current users context

Comment: @mafutrct I'm not sure whether that throws or not -- seems like it should.  Are you logging exceptions?  (are you sure that it is not throwing?)

Comment: @mafutrct Another question: Are you trying to modify the HKCU value for a specific, known user, or just for whoever is logged in.  If the latter, you might be better off not doing this from a service, but instead from a process you load at login (services intentionally run in a separate "sandbox" from logged in users)

Comment: @RobertPitt I would probably make this a program that runs at login, maybe from the user's Run registry key.  that way it will always run within the context of the currently logged-in user.  The user's account should have write privileges to its own HKCU key out of the box, so your code could run in the background from there.  If you want to get fancy, you could make it a task tray app.

Comment: Also if exception occurs during operation..it might be written to EventViewer log ..you can check window's eventviewer ...

Comment: and if you want to debug a windows service.you can add system.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); line on your service  onStart method code

Comment: i check the eventlog, obviusly but it does not show exception events, i think the issue is because of the local account, how can I run the service in the currect user scope, Machine settings are not possible as the proxy system for the company is set to use the current user settings in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't have a clue about registry in C#. These are just guesses.

1. Did you try F11-stepping through the code? Maybe the flow is not as expected? Is the code even run?
2. Did SetValue return a value indicating failure?
3. Does the path possibly have to end in a backslash?
4. Did Windows redirect the write call to a virtual path? Check by reading the key right after writing and compare to a manual look into the registry.

**Update** re your comment:

Executing in a console app to check for errors is a very good idea. Since that worked, point 3 can be removed - the rest is still valid. Maybe windows is writing to a virtual path for your server user?

Try running the console app as the service user (also using F11).

Comment: Ccan't F11 as the application is installed to the registry and is only executed under the service manager, there are now exceptions thrown on the setter and it returns void, 3. no, 4. i have tested the same set code under a console app and works file.